# How to avoid data race with GCD DispatchWorkItem.notify?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, thread-sanitizer

With Swift 3.1 on XCode 8.3, running the following code with the Thread Sanitizer finds a data race (see the write and read comments in the code):

```
  private func incrementAsync() {
    let item = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      strongSelf.x += 1 // <--- the write

      // Uncomment following line and there's no race, probably because print introduces a barrier
      //print("> DispatchWorkItem done")
    }
    item.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      print("> \(strongSelf.x)") // <--- the read
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: item)
  }
```

This seems pretty strange to me as the documentation for the `DispatchWorkItem` mentions that it allows:

> getting notified about their completion

which implies that the `notify` callback is called once the work item's execution is done.

So I would expect that there would be a `happens-before` relationship between the `DispatchWorkItem`'s work closure and its notify closure. What would be the correct way, if any, to use a `DispatchWorkItem` with a registered `notify` callback like this that wouldn't trigger the Thread Sanitizer error?

I tried registering the `notify` with `item.notify(flags: .barrier, queue: .main) ...` but the race persisted (probably because the flag only applies to the same queue, documentation is sparse on what the `.barrier` flag does). But even calling notify on the same (background) queue as the work item's execution, with the `flags: .barrier`, results in a race.

If you wanna try this out, I published the complete XCode project on github here: https://github.com/mna/TestDispatchNotify

There's a `TestDispatchNotify` scheme that builds the app without tsan, and `TestDispatchNotify+Tsan` with the Thread Sanitizer activated.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: This can no longer be manifested. They’ve been revising and enhancing the thread sanitizer, so I suspect that this was merely a bug in an early iteration of TSAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (2019-01-07):** As mentioned by @Rob in a comment on the question, this can't be reproduced anymore with recent versions of Xcode/Foundation (I don't have Xcode installed anymore, I won't guess a version number). There is no workaround required.

---

Well looks like I found out. Using a `DispatchGroup.notify` to get notified when the group's dispatched items have completed, instead of `DispatchWorkItem.notify`, avoids the data race. Here's the same-ish snippet without the data race:

```
  private func incrementAsync() {
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

    let item = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      strongSelf.x += 1
    }

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      print("> \(strongSelf.x)")
    }
    queue.async(group: group, execute: item)
  }
```

So `DispatchGroup` introduces a happens-before relationship and `notify` is safely called after the threads (in this case, a single async work item) finished execution, while `DispatchWorkItem.notify` doesn't offer this guarantee.

Comment: `DispatchWorkItem` should guarantee no race for a _single_ execution. The race for your situation would seem to come from executing the Block multiple times and then notifying on a separate queue (that's not synchronized with respect to the work queue). If you haven't seen it, I think the explanation of the behavior in the docs for `dispatch_block_notify()` is better.

Comment: It is a single execution, though. Each time the method is called, it creates a new DispatchWorkItem that executes just once. Thanks for the heads-up about the docs, it does mention using DispatchGroup there! Looks like the swift docs haven't quite caught up in some places.

Comment: Hm, yes, you're absolutely right. I got myself mixed up puzzling it over.

Comment: @mna please see my "answer". It is not about thread-safe data read, write. I just would like to explain why you are wrong and why you answer should not be accepted as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var job = DispatchWorkItem {
    for i in 0..<3 {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("job", i)
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("job done")
    }
}
job.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("job notify")
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: job)
usleep(100)
job.cancel()
```

if you guess that this snippet prints out

```
job 0
job 1
job 2
job done
job notify
```

you are absolutely right!
increase a deadLine ...

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01, execute: job)
```

and you've got

```
job notify
```

even though the job executes never

notify has nothing with synchronization of any data captured by DispatchWorkItem's closure.

**Let try this example with DispatchGroup!**

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


let group = DispatchGroup()
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("group notify")
}
```

And see the result

```
group notify
```

**!!! WTF !!! Do you still think you solved the race in your code?**
To synchronize any read, write ... use the serial queue, barrier, or semaphore. Dispatch group is totally different beast :-) With dispatch groups you can group together multiple tasks and either wait for them to complete or receive a notification once they complete.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let job1 = DispatchWorkItem {
    sleep(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("job 1 done")
    }
}
let job2 = DispatchWorkItem {
    sleep(2)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("job 2 done")
    }
}
let group = DispatchGroup()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(group: group, execute: job1)
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(group: group, execute: job2)

print("line1")
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("group notify")
}
print("line2")
```

prints

```
line1
line2
job 1 done
job 2 done
group notify
```